# R: How to select files in directory which satisfy conditions both on the beginning and end of name?

Tags: r, design-patterns

I need to select files which start with "M" and end with "*.csv". I can easily select  files which start with "M" : list.files(pattern="^M"), or files which end with "csv": list.files(pattern = "*.csv"). But how to select files which satisfy both conditions at the same time?

Answer (score 20):

You could try `glob2rx`

```
lf <- list.files("path_to_directory/", pattern=glob2rx("M*.csv"))
```

which translates to:

```
glob2rx("M*.csv")
[1] "^M.*\\.csv$"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know about this useful function. It works.

Answer (score 5):

The `pattern` argument takes a regular expression:

```
list.files(pattern='^M.*csv')
```

To be more specific, your second expression:

```
list.files(pattern='.csv')
```

Is matching all files with the string `csv` preceded by any character.  To be explicit and only match files with a `.csv` extension:

```
list.files(pattern='\\.csv$')
```