# How to update a data frame using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, time-series

I have a script which I need to update. The script runs through a csv directory which is updated daily and fills a dataframe with the details of the csv. I want to modify the script so that the script only runs through the newly added csv files only, not the files it scanned the day before. How can it be done?

Comment: how is the naming scheme for the .csv files? maybe something like:
`list.files(pattern = "*.csv")` can be useful? if the date is included in the csv name this works quite well. for example `list.files(pattern = "*26.08.2020.csv")`

Comment: @user12440276 thanks for the response. Yes date is included in the file name. The name of csv files are like 'Copy of Maps - Aug 26 2020.csv'. So, I just want to read the file added today, not the file I added in the directory every past day of this month. What should I do?

Comment: keep the names of checked files in a vector (or a text file). process only those csvs that do not appear in the checked list. alternatively, save the date stamp every time you process the csvs, and next time, process only those files that are newer than the last saved date stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in that case i think the command would look something like this:

```
list_of_new_maps <- list.files(pattern="*Aug 26 2020.csv") # there are probably _ so it would be Aug_26_2020.csv (i assume).
```

if there are multiple new files you have to discern the changes between them but the idea stays the same.

this might be helpful:

[R: How to select files in directory which satisfy conditions both on the beginning and end of name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585413/r-how-to-select-files-in-directory-which-satisfy-conditions-both-on-the-beginni)

EDIT

```
this might be helpful insofar as you can always just take the last result to continue

z<-for (i in 1:30) { # here month length would be more suitable to account for the variation 28/29-31
  if (i<10) {
    
    new_stuff<-paste0(".*202010",i,".csv$") # for days from 1-9 here it would be january 2020 -> 2020_1_01-09. to be more inclusive of changing months you might have to tick up that part of the name as well
    csv_list<-list.files(pattern = new_stuff)
    print(csv_list)
  }
  else{
    
    new_stuff<-paste0(".*20201",i,".csv$") # for days 10-28/31
    csv_list<-list.files(pattern = new_stuff)
    print(csv_list)
  }

}
z

z$csv_list[[length(z$csv_list)]] #last entry / newest input to list
```